How to prevent NuxtJS from combining all CSS files
I'm building a website in NuxtJS and I have two pages, the index.vue and a blog.vue, each with their own external CSS file in the assets directory under the same name as the vue file (index.css and blog.css).
However, when I run the dev command and test the website the styles from the related blog.css will override the same styles from the index.css file despite the fact that the index.vue file only imports the index.css file.
The best example is with the unordered list styles, where in index.css it is set with list-style-type: none; and in blog.css it is set to list-style-type: circle;
Related code:
index.vue
<script>
  import "~/assets/css/index.css";
</script>

index.css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

blog.vue
<script>
  import "../assets/css/blog.css";
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <ContentDoc />
  </main>
</template>

blog.css
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

I've tried using the in-built  tags instead, using the /public directory instead of /assets and even setting the webpack option extractCSS to both true and false to see if it would change anything.
Edit:
I have taken the advice and looked for the Vite build conditions and have tried to fix by setting Vite's build.cssCodeSplit to both true and false and neither has fixed it.
I have also narrowed the problem down somewhat by noticing that when I reload the index page it will first load the expected css file, but then after a few milliseconds will additionally load the blog css file and when I inspect the page's style editor I see the blog.vue file in the list alongside index.vue, index.css, Main.vue, FrameBox.vue and Overlay.vue.
Hiding the blog.vue file in the firefox style editor fixes it, so is there a way to replicate that in the code?

Are you using Webpack or Vite?

It says Vite when I run the dev server.

Try a config for Vite then.

Isn't it prefetching the next page?

how about doing this:
<style lang="css" scoped>
  import "@/assets/css/blog.css";
</script>

and for the index.vue:
<style lang="css" scoped>
  import "@/assets/css/index.css";
</script>

